# How do we remove a 1940 Crane tub spout base adapter that is inside the wall?

Tags: plumbing, tools, bathtub, removal, spout

[image][image]We have a 1940 Crane bathtub spout that leaks when the shower-head is on.  We want to replace the spout, so we have removed it but need to remove the base adapter (correct term?) that is inside the wall. We have been unable to find the right tool that is compatible with the fitter on the old adapter. Does anyone know where we can find one?

Comment: Have any pictures?

Comment: We will take pictures.  In the meantime we have considered using a pipe wrench to remove the adapter ~ which will destroy the threads, but we will need to replace the pipe anyway. We only need to remove the adapter because we need to replace the 1940 spout, and the adapter is not compatible with current spouts on the market. We would prefer to find a Crane 1940 replacement spout but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: I have attached two photos of the spout and adapter.

Comment: I've never seen anything like it.  Are you sure the escutcheon is part of the adapter?  It looks like it might pop off from the picture.  If not, it seems like the adapter tightens to the wall from the inside.  Do you have access to the back?

Comment: We removed the spout ourselves and it was attached to the adapter.  A major plumbing store in our town said the same thing ~ they've never seen anything like it either.  We have since called a Plumber to assist us. Unfortunately we will probably need to remove some tile on the tub side to fix this problem, then put a chrome plate over that area ~ tile is very old and can't be matched. There is tile on the other side of the wall in another bathroom so we can't access from there.

Comment: Too bad you can't save it.  As for the tile; you might be surprised.  It looks like it might be a common tile from the era.  People who do a lot of demo probably come across it on a regular basis.  If you are willing to spend time/money I almost guarantee you can find it.  I might have even pulled some of that tile from my home a couple of years ago! Probably not worth the effort though, since you can't keep the fixture.

Comment: I have the same type in my home and are looking to replace. Were you successful in finding out what to do? Thanks -- Jim

Answer (score 3):

FIXED IT. I found a better solution: heat-shrink tubing. I couldn't get gasket material to reliably adhere to the metal with epoxy, as Tim suggested.

I used heat-shrink tubing with an expanded diameter of ~1.5 inches. It's 3M brand, but I'm not sure which specific product. I used a hair dryer to shrink it because I don't have a heat gun.

It seals well and has held up almost a year already with no obvious signs of wear. When it does wear out, I'll cut it off and shrink another piece on.
[image: Heat-shrink tubing as gasket]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 1):

86-31220 Crane spout adapter will work for your problem. "bathroom machineries" has an adapter to fix this. Google the name and number.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED IT. I can so relate to the posts here. I have the same spout in one of bathrooms in my 1939 home. It was the Cadillac of its day and local plumbing shops have breathlessly admired it - but no one could figure out what to do with it. I also saw many posts on the internet with homeowners frustrated and dreading the need to tear out a wall and replace all the associated fittings.

I tried many ideas because I too did not want to get into the wall. Plus, this is a classic fixture I would prefer to keep. My fix was so simple, but it took several attempts to get it right. I had to purchase some 1/32" thick gasket material. I picked it up from AutoZone. It is a rubberized gray material. I cut a gasket to fit on the BACKSIDE of the diverter plunger. I earlier tried with 1/16" rubber gasket material, but it was too thick. I also smeared black gutter leak fix on the brass opening - this slowed down the flow but did not stop it entirely. Make sure the plunger and the brass opening are clean before applying a 2-part epoxy. I used JB Weld 5 minute epoxy. Hopefully it will last.
[image: Gasket]